# Forward urls on same domain to different servers

Tags: iis, .net, iis-8

During a rollout of a large site (IIS, .NET, EPiServer) with multiple markets we want to forward markets to the new server when the market has been added to the new web platform, but we still want to use the same domain.

> www.customer.com/sv-SE/ -> old server, ip 1.1.1.1
>   www.customer.com/en-UK/ -> old server, ip 1.1.1.1
>   www.customer.com/de-DE/ -> new server, ip 2.2.2.2

What is best practice for this? 
Should we add a load balancer in front of the servers that based on the url sends the traffic to the correct server or is it possible to do this on dns level, or should we let all traffic go to one server and redirect the traffic with urlrewrite to the new server. Or is there any other alternatives? 
(The rollout will take at least 6 month)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can't be done via DNS. It's only job is to translate names to IPs (and vice-versa).

A Layer 7 load-balancer or reverse-proxy could do what you want fairly easily.